# When I package my project into a .jar with eclipse, it can't find lwjgl

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, lwjgl

When I run the jar from the command prompt, it says there's no lwjgl in java.library.path.

My java build path for the project has lwjgl.jar checked in the order and export section, and when I open the jar with 7zip it says there's a lwjgl.jar in there.

I've tried exporting using "extract required libraries into generated jar" and "package required libraries into generated jar", but to no avail.

Edit: Here's the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
    at main.Game.initGL(Game.java:63)
    at main.Game.start(Game.java:25)
    at main.Game.main(Game.java:90)
```

Comment: Please show the *exact* error. I suspect the problem is trying to find the native library, not the jar file...

Comment: No, please edit the exact error *as text* into the question. Someone trying to help you shouldn't have to click on a link to see what is basically plain text.

Comment: Ok, I added it to the body.